# File conversion between .fasta and .genbank format

Tags: python, fasta, genbank

I have to create two functions that should allow me to open `.genbank` files and convert them into a `.fasta` file and the other way around. What I have for the moment is this:

```
def Convert(file, file1)
    handle_input=open('file', 'rU')
    handle_output=open('file1', 'w')
        while True:
        s=handle_input.readline()
        t=handle_output.write(s, '.genbank')
    print(t)
Convert('file.fas', 'file.genbank')
```

It is also probably not correct, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: why are you looping with while True?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of documentation about this on the internet. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

But to get you started:
I assume that the 2 files will not be identical in the future because otherwise you can just copy the file.

I have couple of remarks.

1) Your loop `while true` will run till the end of time. Change it to something like

`for line in handle_input:`

2)Close your files when you are done:

`handle_input.close()
handle_output.close()`

3)`t=handle_output.write(s, '.genbank')`
Remove the '.genbank' argument

4) No need to do `print(t)`

Note: I havent tested this code so I could have made some small mistakes